# Formik component not being rendered with react-tabs

Tags: reactjs, formik, react-tabs

I'm trying to use [react-tabs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tabs) with [Formik](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formik) but everytime i put the `<Formik>` tag, nothing gets rendered. This is what i'm trying to do:

```
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Typography className={classes.headerText}>Editar lojista</Typography>
      <Tabs>
        <TabList>
          <Tab>Loja e responsável</Tab>
          <Tab>Segurança</Tab>
        </TabList>
        <Formik
          initialValues={this.getInitalValues()}
          onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              // alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
              setSubmitting(false);
              console.log(values);
            }, 400);
          }}
          validationSchema={schema}>
          {({
            values,
            errors,
            touched,
            handleChange,
            handleBlur,
            handleSubmit,
            isSubmitting
            /* and other goodies */
          }) => (
            <form className={classes.form}>
              <TabPanel>
                <MainLojistaForm /> {/* this is one component */}
              </TabPanel>
              <TabPanel>
                <SegurancaForm /> {/* this is one component */}
              </TabPanel>
              <div className={classes.saveContainer}>
                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  type="submit"
                  className={classes.button}>
                  Salvar
                </Button>
              </div>
            </form>
          )}
        </Formik>
      </Tabs>
    </div>
```

And this is a printscreen of what it looks like without Formik:
[image: react-tabs]

I really dont know what i'm doing wrong. Anyone ever had this issue?
The unique error i get is from react-tabs:

> 1.chunk.js:252727 Warning: Failed prop type: There should be an equal number of 'Tab' and 'TabPanel' in `UncontrolledTabs`. Received 2 'Tab'
>   and 0 'TabPanel'.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but aren't you supposed to render the TabPanels as direct children of the Tabs component? If so, you should render the Tabs component inside the Formik and form components.

Comment: Try putting `Formik` and `form` wrapping `Tabs`

Comment: It worked @Vencovsky

Comment: Thanks to you too, @Christiaan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is put `Formik` and `form` wrapping `Tabs`.